# JQuery & Child selector A > B: not working ? [Chrome 24, JQmobile]

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-selectors

**Given the nested html:**

```
<a class="star">Hello world!
 <a class="ui-icon-star"> hello </a>
</a>
```

I used **the following JS:**

```
$('.star').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("favorited");
    $(this > '.ui-icon-star').toggleClass("ui-icon-starred");
});
```

to change both the .star and the child .ui-icon-star elements, but it doesn't work with the child. Where is my [selector(?)] mistake ? Around $(this > '.ui-icon-star') i guess.

1: http://jsfiddle.net/tNwND/1/
2: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html

Comment: Maybe?: $(this).find('.ui-icon-star').toggleClass("ui-icon-starred");

Comment: "this" cannot combine with other selectors ?

Comment: an `<a>` tag inside another `<a>` tag is illegal HTML. The browser's rendering engine will freak out at that, but different browsers may well handle it differently.

Comment: Your link Markdown is malformed. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links for help in formatting your links correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because your markup is invalid, browser renders your markup this way:

```
<a class="star">Hello world! </a>
<a class="ui-icon-star"> hello </a>
```

So the clicked element doesn't have `.ui-icon-star` child element.

Comment: After replacing <a> by divs  it [do the same](http://jsfiddle.net/tNwND/5/) (fails). Maybe a specifics to JQM or I did something wrong again?

Comment: @Hugolpz If you use an inspector you can see that the markup is rendered the same way as you have written it, by removing background property you can see the effect better http://jsfiddle.net/w66Rv/